# Recommend an approach for 'modeling' localized strings for the view?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

We are beginning to approach the localization of our site and most of the mechanisms are in place (setting the ui culture, settings up the resx files) however I'm wondering how to approach the delivery of those strings. For the first few, I just created properties in the viewmodel where the getter pulls from the resource file like:

`{ get { rm.GetString("Greeting", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture); } }`

But what I'm wondering is what other people are doing. Should the view model just have a bunch of string properties like this? Do you stuff it into view data? Maybe build a dictionary in the view model to pull from in the view? I'm not sure what a clean manageable way would be, so I'm looking for ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using auto-generated resource accessor class ([Running PublicResXFileCodeGenerator at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039158/running-publicresxfilecodegenerator-at-compile-time)) and simply rendering strings in a view using whatever rending engine you prefer is simple and straightforward version. Razor sample below:

```
 @* assuming CurrentUICulture is set correctly for whole request *@
 <span>@Resource.DirectionsTitle</span>
```

If you need to pass localized strings to JavaScript - rendering in a view in script tag is possible option (don't forget proper encoding).

Comment: Sure but how does that work with the view models when you need model binding??

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - I see nothing wrong with your approach if you really need model to have localized string as properties... I'm not exactly sure what are your use cases, so I don't know if there anything significantly better than your approach.

Comment: I guess what I was really asking was how would you localize the string in the Display attribute of the viewmodel. But I found that you can use ResourceType and then Name becomes the name of the Key in the resource file.